# transferring a lot of images over XMPP

Tags: xmpp, file-transfer

I need to send a lot of images over `XMPP`(an app that users use to send and receive images in real time). Now `XMPP` has support for sending binary data and the clients can send images over `XMPP`. But in cases where the server has to store lot of pending images to send to clients which are currently offline, it might be a lot of piled up load. So what i am considering is this

1. `user_A` uses the app to send an image to `user_B`.
2. The image is uploaded by `user_A`'s app to `Amazon S3` and its `bucket` and `key` is sent over `XMPP` to `user_B`.
3. The app of `user_B` gets the bucket and key of the image and starts downloading it from `S3`.

Is this a good way to do things or i should be using something else?
Thanks

Comment: yes this is a good idea. See also XEP-0066 Out of Band Data http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0066.html

Comment: he wont be able to send pictures to offline contacts using XEP-0066

Answer (score 1):

best way to do this is to send the images within a message stanza in base64.

sending it over a message stanzas ensure the pictures will be received in real time or whenever the user is online. avoid using vCards because there's a limitation of the size (less 200KB)

Comment: Is XMPP good for constantly sending images that are 600-700 KB in size each?

Comment: no, this is a bad idea and not recommended. If you have 10 offline messages in your storage with 700KB then you client automatically gets delivered those messages on your next login from the offline storage. Your session is blogged until you have received this 7MB of data.

Comment: that really depends on the server and how efficient your code is. you can send any data of any size using xmpp, you just have to manage it properly.